# Gradle test task is not run after specifying a group

Tags: gradle, testng

I'm setting up some tests. I have the following entries in my `build.gradle` file:

```
integTest {
   useTestNG() {
   }
}

integTest2 (type: Test){
   useTestNG() {
      include 'Group2'
   }
}
```

And in my test I have the following annotation:

```
@Test (groups={"Group2"})
public void testMethod() {
  // Test code here

}
```

When I run the second task (`integTest2`) with gradle it only *builds* my directory and doesn't actually pick up any tests to run (`integTest` works fine and runs all the tests but I want to be able to run separate suites individually too).

Is there something obvious I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer. I was using our company's internal version of gradle which  only recognized "integTest" as the main task. So as a workaround I had to do something like this:

```
def allTestGroups = ['all', 'Group1', 'Group2']
def testGroup = project.hasProperty("testGroup") ? project.testGroup : 'all'


integTest {
  useTestNG() {
     includeGroups "${testGroup}"
    excludeGroups allTestGroups.findAll { it != "${testGroup}" }.collect { "'${it}'" }.join(',')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change `include 'Group2'` to `includeGroups 'Group2'`, like this:

```
integTest2 (type: Test) {
   useTestNG {
      includeGroups 'Group2'
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no change. It only builds the directory only :(